# Two discriminants

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I have a question on the discriminant by two different sides.

Let $\alpha \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ be any algebraic number. Let $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ be its minimal polynomial and write it $f(x) = a \prod_{i=1}^d(x-\alpha_i)$, with $\alpha = \alpha_1$ and $d \geq 2$. Let also

$$D(f) := a^{2d-2}\prod_{i<j}(\alpha_i-\alpha_j)^2,$$

be the discriminant of $f(x)$.

Is it true that discriminant of the field $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is the same as $D(f)$? If not, how are these two discriminants related?

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, i found the solution.

The discriminant of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is $discr(1,\alpha,\alpha^2,...,\alpha^{d-1})$ which, by a theorem, equals to

$$\frac1{a^{2d-2}}D(f).$$